# navigating between simple activities

Tags: android

**Hello**

[image: fig]

*I want to know how this concept is implemented in android*

- Navigation in this application takes place like this::

> Activity1- -- to- -  -> Activity 2- -to - -.>Activity 3 - - to - ->
>   Activity2

**But on doing  this ::**

*I pass the data from*

> Activity1 - - > Activity 2- -> I do not pass the data from Activity2 -
>   - > Activity3

**Now**

> If I navigate back to Activity2- - from - - Activity3

- The application closes because Activity2 is expecting the data which
  is not present in Activity3
- How can I overcome this, how can I preserve the state(even data) of
  activity 2 before navigating back from Activity3

**Cycle has to be ::**

> Activity1- -- to- -  -> Activity 2- -to - -.>Activity 3 - - to - ->
>   Activity2

---

- How to achieve this?
- What concepts do i need to look for

I hope i am clear with my description

---

### I have given a sample program to support my question

how to modify code to achieve this

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity1);

        Button BTN=(Button) findViewById(R.id.activity3button3);
        BTN.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent INT=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Activity2.class);
                INT.putExtra("hi", "HI");
                startActivity(INT);     
            }
        }); 
    }

 }
```

**Activity2.java**

```
public class Activity2 extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity2);



        Button BTN=(Button) findViewById(R.id.activity3button3);

        BTN.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Intent INT=new Intent(Activity2.this,Activity3.class);
                startActivity(INT);

            }
        });

    }



}
```

**Activity3.java**

```
public class Activity3 extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity3);

        Button BTN=(Button) findViewById(R.id.activity3button3);

        BTN.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent INT=new Intent(Activity3.this,Activity2.class);
                startActivity(INT);
            }
        });



    }



}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are using multiple activities instead of multiple fragments within a single activity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be this will help

You have `R.layout.activity1`, `R.layout.activity2` and `R.layout.activity3` in that you need give separate button for all but you have given as `R.id.activity3button3` one one button for all so better create three button for three activity

```
Button BTN=(Button) findViewById(R.id.activity1button1);
        BTN.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                     Intent ide = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Activity2.class);
                     ide .putExtra("hi", "HI");
                 ide.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                     startActivity(ide);
            }
        }); 



  Button BTN=(Button) findViewById(R.id.activity2butto2);
            BTN.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                         Intent ide = new Intent(Acitvity2.this,Acitvity3.class);
                         ide .putExtra("hi", "HI");
                         ide.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                         startActivity(ide);
                }
            }); 

Button BTN=(Button) findViewById(R.id.activity3button3);
        BTN.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                     Intent ide = new Intent(Acitvity3.this,Acitvity2.class);
                     ide .putExtra("hi", "HI");
                 ide.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                     startActivity(ide);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 3):

There are few options you can use.

Method 1:

> In Activty 2 you can save some data using onSaveInstanceIndtance().
>   This function is just called before onDestroy. In onCreate() you can
>   retrieve the saved data using onRetroreInstanceState()

Method 2:

> You can save data in sharedPrefernces. At any point in any activity
>   you can get the data saved in sharedPreference.

Method 3:

> You can start your activity2 with "singleTask" flag. So while coming
>   back from Activity 3 to Activty 2, previous instance will be called
>   from stack. In this case onCreate() wont be called for Activtiy 2.
>   Rather onNewIntent() will be called.

You can use one of them as per your need.

Comment: It looks like we have 5 solutions, then :)

Comment: Actually there are may ways to tackle this problem. Probably in your case you can just set the flag "singleTask" for activity 2. Will be easiest to do :)

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1** is to keep passing value:

```
Intent INT=new Intent(Activity2.this,Activity3.class);
INT.putExtra("hi", getIntent().getStringExtra("hi","error");
startActivity(INT);
```

and again

```
Intent INT=new Intent(Activity3.this,Activity2.class);
INT.putExtra("hi", getIntent().getStringExtra("hi","error");
startActivity(INT);
```

**Solution 2** is to create one static variable that will hold value and that will be accessible all across application.

```
public class DataHolder {
    public static String hi;
}
```

and in Activity2 instead of fetching value from Bundle, just get it from DataHolder:

```
String hi = DataHolder.hi;
```

These are two things that first came on my mind.

Comment: Your First Solution is Very good thinking .... thanks for sharing the information :)

Comment: Thank you. But be careful, because it can be messy. 
You should, also, consider @Sushil 's 3th solution and set launchMode = "singleTask". If it works for you, it is most elegant solution.