# FindViewById<Button> is returning Null

Tags: xamarin.android

So I am adding new button to my app but when FindViewById is called it returns null and app crashes. **In my .cs file I have following function:**

```
void fooUIButtonHandler()  
{  
    var fooUIButton = FindViewById(Resource.Id.fooUIButton);  
    fooUIButton.Click += delegate  
    {  
        if (!CheckOriginalImage()) 
        { 
            return; 
        } 

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(fooImageDemoActivity));  
        intent.PutExtra(fooImageDemoActivity.EXTRAS_ARG_IMAGE_FILE_URI,   
            originalImageUri.ToString());  
        StartActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_SB_FOO_UI);  
    };  
}
```

**and my .axml file looks like this:**

```
<Button  
    android:id="@+id/fooUIButton"  
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
    android:background="#0b8442"  
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"  
    android:text="foo"/>
```

**I am setting Content View in OnCreate:**

```
SetContentView(Resource.Layout.FooDocumentCreation);
```

**and then calling:**

```
fooUIButtonHandler()
```

**But following line is throwing Null exception:**

```
var fooUIButton = FindViewById(Resource.Id.fooUIButton);
```

Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25209916/xamarin-findviewbyid-returns-null?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Try clean & build. also are you sure the `fooUIButton` is inside `FooDocumentCreation`?

Comment: Also, you can delete the bin and obj folder in your project, and restart your VS.